# "no such column: id" Django AbstractUser model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to migrate, and view the admin page. both makemigrations and migrate passed, yet when i go to the admin url it reads this: "django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: social_app_user.id"

And once i create an id field, it changes to "django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: social_app_user.password"

I was under the impression that the AbstractUser model included all the default user fields, not sure about the primary key, but regardless.

Please help, thanks!

Note: the 'id' field in this models.py file was added after i got the error.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects =  UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        f"{self.username} {self.email}"
        return


class main_feed(models.Model):
    content= models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255, default='', null=False)
    poster = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='author', on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='username')
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    favorites = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        f"{self.content} {self.likes} {self.poster} {self.date_posted}"
        return
```

Comment: if you open up the migrations that were generated do you see a `migrations.CreateModel` with name="User" and a fields list?  Are id and password among those fields?

Comment: @CameronMcFee Yes. I just checked the migrations file and the User model is there with an id field, as well as all the other user fields.

Comment: Can you share your `admin.py`?

Comment: When you migrate, are you able to open the database to inspect the user table? Sometimes you have to `makemigrations <app name>`

Comment: @Jarad I am not able to open the admin database page without seeing this error, and makemigrations passes with no issue. And my admin.py file just has a register user and import user.

Comment: @beatmaister if your current database was `db.sqlite`, do you see that file in your project after migrating? If yes, you should open it up. I inspect mine with PyCharm, but you can use something like SQLiteStudio if you currently have no idea how to open a database and inspect it. You should look to see if the user table actually exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had to restart my entire application and run startapp again.
This time i added the user model and set up the settings and admin file BEFORE the very first migration. then everything works dandy. But I have no idea why this is the case, shouldnt the migration update and override the default user model?
anyways the question is answered now.